# Read a text with certain pattern in CSV file

Tags: matlab, csv

I have `Excel CSV file` which has some text and data. In `CSV file`, for example, I have statements, as following (I have many statements and data after each statement. The following 2 statements is just an example):

```
1_Q6 - Walmart (https://www.glassdoor.com)
5_Q5 - Phillips 66 (https://www.glassdoor.com)
```

So, I wish to read words only `"Walmart"` from the first statement in the first row and `"Phillips 66"` from the second statement in the second row. As you can see, the location of both these word have a pattern. It is succeeded by a hyphen and blank space. It has pattern like following:

```
_Qnumber - "The word I am interested in" (
```

So, to summarize, I wish to read the word that is succeeded by `"_Qnumber -"` and preceded by `" ("` . That `"number"` is always going to be `5 or 6`.

I hope you get what I am trying to achieve. I have already tried using `xlsread` and `textscan` but no success.

Thanks a lot for your help in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Textscan works well for me:

```
>> type textscan.dat % show contents of file
1_Q6 - Walmart (https://www.glassdoor.com)
5_Q5 - Phillips 66 (https://www.glassdoor.com)
```

```
>> f = fopen ('textscan.dat', 'r');        
>> C = textscan (f, '%*u_%*c%u - %s %*[^\n]')
C = 
    [2x1 uint32]    {2x1 cell}
>> C{:}
ans =
           6
           5
ans = 
    'Walmart'
    'Phillips'
```

PS. Don't forget that if you need to re-read `f`, you'll have to `frewind(f)` first. Also, don't forget to `fclose(f)`.

Comment: I won't explain the specifiers I used because I only just figured them out myself, heheh. Read the matlab helpfile, it's very clear. :)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html

These are the functions that you are looking for.